# How to get SSIS to import an Excel file with non-default Worksheet name?

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that loops through a folder and imports all the excel files into an OLEDB destination. The package works fine as long as all the worksheet names are set to default. It breaks if the worksheet name is different. There are a couple of examples online on how to import multiple worksheets. **How do I get SSIS to import an Excel file with non-default Worksheet name?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Programming Foreach Loop Container – Enumerating Excel Sheets](http://www.sqllion.com/2009/06/programming-foreach-loop-container-%E2%80%93-enumerating-excel-sheets/).  It uses a Foreach Loop container to iterate over whatever sheets are in the workbook.

Comment: I have seen your post before. But I am looking for guidance on just one sheet in excel that has different sheet name everytime. I am pretty new to SSIS and it is hard for me to arrive at something from the post!

Comment: Doesn't matter if you just have one sheet that's named differently every time, or ten sheets.  The point is that post will iterate over "all" the sheets (even if it's only one).  On each iteration (again, only one) it'll give you the sheet name so you can use it in your source query.

Answer (score 1):

You can set OpenRowSet property of Excel Source. Something like "MyNotDefaultWorksheet".
You can also set this property from package variable and then set this variable programmatically.